# Get all grid values on a diagonal line from point to point in xarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray, metpy

I'm looking to select all data from an `xarray` dataset that is between one point and another. This is of course easy with `sel` for example with a dataset based on a lat/lon grid to subset from a global dataset to the Atlantic coastline I can do `ds_geo_subset = ds.sel( lat=slice(42, 20), lon=slice(-85,-65))` but I want to select all data along the Gulf Stream front, basically from to point (-78 lon, 32 lat) to (-72 lon, 36 lat) but I'm not sure how to do this. Would this be best done by giving a full point dataset and getting data from each point or can these two end points be given to xarray and interpolated data returned?

Comment: You can find a solution for a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326202/how-to-plot-a-vertical-section-of-the-atmosphere-along-with-the-topography-using/58343518#58343518

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment above suggested, `Metpy` has a specific function which can be handy for this task.

```
from metpy.interpolate import cross_section

data = xr.open_dataset('my_data')

# Define start and end points:

start = (-78, 32)
end = (-72, 36)
cross = cross_section(data, start, end).set_coords(('lat', 'lon'))
```

[Here](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/cross_section.html?highlight=cross%20section) is a nice example to plot a cross-section.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with "pure" xarray?